C# Live Chart X axis
Let's say i have 2 set of data:
1st Set:
X Data = {1.0,1.2,2.5}
Y Data = {1,2,3}
2nd Set:
X Data = {1.5,2.3,3}
Y Data = {1,2,3}
How can i plot both graph with correct x-axis shift in C# Live Chart WPF?
I not able to label the map the data in x-axis correctly.
